# How to login SSH on Azure Databricks cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks

I used the following ubuntu command to access SSH login as,

ssh user@hostname_or_IP

- Can able to see Master node hostname
- but not able to get the username from Azure Databricks cluster

Refer this doc,
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/clusters/spark-config.html#spark-config

Comment: You need to use the Cluster API to SSH into an existing cluster. You can see more details in this document: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/ssh.html  It should be work for Azure too.

Comment: that code works fine. I know the hostname of both Driver node & worker node. But I want to log in on ssh from the terminal, what is the username for existing cluster in Azure data bricks? Where to find that? @WayneYang-MSFT

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your qustion, I upvote  for you, I under stand why you need this feature, but for now, it's not possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot SSH to the Cluster for now.

I did a test in my lab:

There was a **SSH** section in the Cluster configuration. But now, we cannot see it here.

[image]

Also, I found the VMs behind the Databricks in a resource group, I try to change the SSH configuration from portal but failed. Then I found the Databricks resource group has been locked to Read-Only. You cannot delete it from portal neither.

[image]

I tried to found the cause why cannot SSH the Cluster behind the Databricks, I saw the NSG rule of the VMs which belongs to that Databricks :

[image]

It means that Azure Databricks only allow only one source to SSH the VM, and the source is Databricks control plane . We can also understand this in the picture of Architecture of Azure Databricks:

[image]

Azure Databricks is a very new feature in Azure. I believe it will be better in future.You can post your idea in [Azure Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) or in [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-technical-overview-of-azure-databricks/)'s comment. Azure Team will review it .

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI,@veilumuthu, If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer, so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Comment: As you mentioned above "VMs which belongs to that Databricks" How will u create VM that belongs to Databricks?

Comment: @veilumuthu Those VMs aren't created by me directly.When you created clusters in your data bricks,it would be created automatically in a resource group. You can find in Azure portal.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation is copied from Databricks equivalent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/clusters/azure-ssh-cluster-driver-node. As there is no SSH-option available, I left feedback with request to either enable SSH or update the docs.

Comment: You need to enable VNet injection and have public subnet in it. Driver node will be assigned a public IPv4-address and can be configured to allow SSH into it. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject

Answer (score 3):

this is maybe a newer feature (https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/clusters/ssh.html still not documented)
but it is possible to set up ssh

in the 'public vnet' that Azure databricks sets up and puts driver VMs on, you need go to the Network Security group for it and add port 2200 (note, not the default SSH port 22) for inbound connections

this is what an Azure support specialist sent me:

[image]

then you can set up your public key in the cluster in the SSH tab under Advanced cluster settings
and you should be able to connect!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you cannot SSH on Azure Databricks.

**Note:** Azure Databricks integrated with Azure Active Directory – So, Azure Databricks users are only regular AAD users.

- Azure Active Directory users can be used directly in Azure Databricks
  for al user-based access control (Clusters, jobs, Notebooks etc.).
- Azure Databricks has delegated user authentication to AAD enabling
  single-sign on (SSO) and unified authentication.
- Notebooks and their outputs, are stored in the Databricks account.
  However, AAD based access control ensures that only authorized users
  can access them.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to login to a cluster using the following steps:

1. Navigate to the managed Databricks resource group and locate the NSG. This resource group is created for you and is named `databricks-rg-[DataBricks Name]-[hash]`.
2. Update NSG to allow port 22 for any IP (or your IP).
3. Open Azure CLI and run the following command to update the SSH key:

```
# Target the username "ubuntu", update RG and VM, and point to your public key
az vm user update --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM --username ubuntu --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

4. Login with SSH.

```
➜  workspace ssh ubuntu@[PUBLICIP]
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1054-azure x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

49 updates can be applied immediately.
39 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

8 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm

New release '22.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Tue Feb 27 19:57:38 2024 from 184.146.184.127
ubuntu@b7ec68b84e2f4ccbb01c658fb8f268b9:~$ curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01" | jq .compute
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1380  100  1380    0     0   122k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  122k
{
  "location": "eastus",
  "name": "b7ec68b84e2f4ccbb01c658fb8f268b9",
  "offer": "Databricks",
  "osType": "Linux",
  "placementGroupId": "",
  "platformFaultDomain": "0",
  "platformUpdateDomain": "0",
  "publisher": "AzureDatabricks",
  "resourceGroupName": "databricks-rg-dbworkspace1-3crnfrpxbf2ix",
  "sku": "DatabricksWorker",
  "subscriptionId": "[SUBSCRIPTION]",
  "tags": "ClusterId:0216-153144-dshgse6z;ClusterName:[john@company.com]'s Cluster;Created By:1824ceb1-b085-47fc-a634-7d91373b9914;Created TimeStamp:2024-02-27T18:49:12.2027025+00:00;Creator:[john@company.com];DatabricksEnvironment:workerenv-1221580456835277;LastModifiedBy:[john@company.com];LastModifiedTimeStamp:2024-02-27T18:57:23.8139620+00:00;Owner:[john@company.com];ResourceClass:SingleNode;Vendor:Databricks;databricks-instance-name:b7ec68b84e2f4ccbb01c658fb8f268b9;management_service:instance_manager_service",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "vmId": "0f9fee62-2d98-44b2-a376-9574c37a1c8b",
  "vmSize": "Standard_DS3_v2"
}
```